# How to find "show" name with YouTube API v3.0

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

So, the YouTube API v3.0 has a `categoryId` which is titled "Shows". However, when searching on the YouTube website, each of these "Shows" also has its own title (e.g.: "Falling Skies").

I already checked in the channel title (`channel.snippet.title`), and it is not there.
I could not find it anywhere in the documentation, but is there a way to find out the name of each show ?

Comment: I'm also having the same issue, and the reference to the v3 code refers to items that do not exist when returned by the API.